# How to perform any action before submit form in cake php

Tags: cakephp

I have a form in cake php Here i have some hidden field that i want to sent when user click on submit button.
At start hidden field value is blank you can see in given form below 
I set that hidden field value in playTimer() function in js file

But my prob is when i am going to submit that form it have blank value for actionId hidden field in post data  .Wen i again clcik submit then i have value .

I want to set it when user first clcik the submit button so taht i am using before call back function.

```
     echo $this->Form->create('Meditation', array('id' => 'timerform'));
     echo $this->Form->hidden('actionId', array('value'=>'', 'id'=>'actionId'));
     echo $this->Js->submit('Play', array(
                                            'before'    => 'playTimer();',
                                            'update'    => '#map_container',
                                            'complete'  => 'setsessionid();',   
                                            'success'   => 'soundPlay();resume();',
                                            'class'     => 'btn btn-med-success playTimer',
                                            'div'       => false,
                                            'async'     => false,
                                            'url'       => array('action' => 'timerupdateDuo')

                                ));



 ==========Custom.js============ 


      function playTimer(){


        $("#actionId").val('playTimer');

           }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<? echo $this->Form->submit(__('Save'), array(
            'class' => 'ClassOfTheFormSubmitBTN'
        )); ?>   

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){
       $('.ClassOfTheFormSubmitBTN').on('click',function(){

                  // implement your logic here
                  $('#MODELNAMEactionId').val('something');

                  //you can use ajax here with serialize to send the form 
                  //to stop the form from posting return false;
       });
    });
</script>
```